# Batch SET command doesn't give wanted result for replacing character

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd

The code below echo s two "B"s and not one B and an "a".
Can someone explain to me why this is and how to get the result I want.

```
@echo off

set code=A
set code=%code:A=B%
echo %code%

set code=a
set code=%code:A=B%
echo %code%

pause
```

Comment: wow it seems like nobody bothers to answer :(

Comment: If it helps the answer should have the same functionality as the set command but case sensitive.

Comment: Oh no, trust me I've noticed it, I'm just trying to answer it myself...

Comment: thanks I've been googleing for at least an hour

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986001/how-to-search-and-replace-case-sensitive-string-using-batch) or [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1986) ? shame it seems to be so difficult.

Comment: it seems way too complicated but i'll read it

Comment: all of them use a file and not a variable and the answer shouldn't be about file manipulation and they use find what is too slow for putting in a loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095092/string-manipulation-with-case-sensitivity this is the answer ... its - no; case sensitivity by default; but you can tricks; you can try moving it undef IF cause you can run IF /I - everything under that will be case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this and edited it to fit your question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095092/string-manipulation-with-case-sensitivity)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=AaBbCc"
set "result="
for /l %%G in (0,1,999) do (
    set char=!string:~%%G,1!
    if "!char!" equ "A" set "char=B"
    set "result=!result!!char!"
)
echo %result%
endlocal
pause
```

It works by going through each character (max of ~1000) and replacing a literal string "A" with "B". This can be slower on longer strings but should work fine. `delayedExpansion` needs to be enabled to reference the string it builds up 1 character at a time.

Comment: and I think it would be better if we replaced 999 with a variable that has the length of the string right?

Comment: You could shorten it if you know the variable you're going to replace is much shorter yes.