# Replace Uppercase and Lowercase separately in a String

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, uppercase, lowercase

I would like to get this batch to work as expected, but it is not able to detect the upper and lower casing (I do not know how). So here is the thing:

```
@echo off
set /p letter="write letter: "
set var=%letter%
set result1=%var:M=7%
set result2=%result1:m=8%
echo %result2%

pause > nul
exit
```

for now:

When I write "M" in the letter variable, i get 7

When I write "m" in the letter variable, i get 7 also (because it is already converted)

what i want:

when i write "M" i get 7

when i write "m" i get 8

when i write "Mm" i get 78

any help with that? I would like to keep it simple as I am new at this, thanks

Comment: Variable expansion and substitution is case insensitive, therefore you cannot use it to do what you were intending.

Comment: [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986001/how-to-search-and-replace-case-sensitive-string-using-batch) describes a rather complex solution to doing case sensitive replacements.

Answer (score 1):

```batch-file
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

SET "string=string containing M and m"
SET "newstring="

:loop
IF DEFINED string (
 IF "%string:~0,1%" == "M" (
  SET "Newstring=%newstring%7"
 ) ELSE (
  IF "%string:~0,1%" == "m" (
   SET "Newstring=%newstring%8"
  ) ELSE (
   SET "Newstring=%newstring%%string:~0,1%"
  )
 )
 SET string
 SET "string=%string:~1%"
 GOTO loop
)

ECHO newstring=%newstring%

GOTO :EOF
```

Characters that have a special meaning to `cmd` ("Poison characters") will probably cause problems.